# Issue with facebook Login Win10 app

Tags: c#, facebook, xaml, winrt-xaml

I have added the Facebook.dll and the Facebook.Client.dll, this code works fine on the Windows Phone and Windows 8.1 app however its not working on the Windows 10 application coded in XAML and C#.  Is anyone having this issue also?

```
  public async Task<string> LogIntoFacebook()
        {
            //var session = new Session();
            Session FacebookSessionClient = new Session(Constants.FacebookAppId);

            try
            {
                FacebookSessionClient.LoginWithBehavior(_FacebookPermissions, FacebookLoginBehavior.LoginBehaviorAppwithMobileInternetFallback);

                await Session.CheckAndExtendTokenIfNeeded();

            }
            catch (FacebookOAuthException exception)
            {
                SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<IErrorService>().ReportErrorInternalOnly(exception);
                return null;
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
            {
                SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<IErrorService>().ReportErrorInternalOnly(ex);
                return null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<IErrorService>().ReportErrorInternalOnly(ex);
                return null;
            }


            return null;

        }
```

This part "await Session.CheckAndExtendTokenIfNeeded();" should be where the login happens but nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a link: http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/07/14/windows-sdk-for-facebook/

You can find a new Windows SDK for Facebook, it has login it

PS: you can alos look here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-how-to-register-facebook-authentication/